# Directed graph with nested class-based node shapes with ports, individual edge types, and nested object reference anchors?

Tags: svg, graphviz, diagram

There is a specific type of a diagram I'd like to draw automatically - I have an example below of the best I can do in Graphviz, and an edit of that in Inkscape of what I actually want. I am under the impression that what I want it not achievable in plain Graphviz (but I not know it well, so I might be wrong) - so I would very much appreciate suggestion for another diagramming software.

Anyways - overall, I want to print a network of nodes, that have a title, a text list of properties, and a set of ports - and the edge connections are mostly between ports of individual nodes.

Here is an example of the best I can do in Graphviz `dot`:

```graphviz
digraph myNodes {
  rankdir=TB;  //top to bottom
  splines = spline; // polyline; // curved;

  node [shape=Mrecord];
  myNodeA [label="{\
    <top> Title A|\
    <mid> prop_1: yes\lprop_2: some\lprop_3: thing\l|\
    <bot>}|<conn1> conn1 |<conn2> conn2 |<conn3> conn3"];

  myNodeB [label="{\
    <top> Title B|\
    <mid> prop_1: yes\lprop_2: some\lprop_3: thing\l|\
    <bot>}|<conn1> conn1 |<conn2> conn2 |<conn3> conn3"];

  myNodeC [label="{\
    <top> Title C|\
    <mid> prop_1: yes\lprop_2: some\lprop_3: thing\l|\
    <bot>}|<conn1> conn1 |<conn2> conn2 |<conn3> conn3"];

  myNodeD [label="{\
    <top> Title D|\
    <mid> prop_1: yes\lprop_2: some\lprop_3: thing\l|\
    <bot>}|<conn1> conn1 |<conn2> conn2 |<conn3> conn3 |<conn4> conn4 |<conn5> conn5 |<conn6> conn6"];

  edge [dir=both,arrowtail=dot];
  myNodeA:conn1:s -> myNodeB:conn1:n;
  myNodeA:conn2:s -> myNodeB:conn2:n;
  myNodeA:conn3:s -> myNodeB:conn3:n;

  myNodeB:conn1:s -> myNodeD:conn4:n;
  myNodeB:conn2:s -> myNodeD:conn5:n;
  myNodeB:conn3:s -> myNodeD:conn6:e;

  myNodeC:conn1:s -> myNodeD:conn1:n;
  myNodeC:conn2:s -> myNodeD:conn2:n;
  myNodeC:conn3:s -> myNodeD:conn3:n;
}
```

I compiled this with:

```
dot -Tsvg tmp.gv -o tmp.svg
```

and got:

[image: direct dot]

I edited this in Inkscape, to show what I really want:

[image: inkscape edit]

Trying to put what I want in words:

- I want to define node shape types/classes, that contain distinct "boxes" to act as "ports", which can act as endpoints of edges/connections

  - A code-only approach would have to allow for nested classes, so I can define a "class" for a Port, and then use multiple "instances" of that "class" in a "class" for a custom node shape (not sure to what extent is this doable in Graphviz)
  - But, what I would *really* like, is the ability to use nested Inkscape SVG documents (when Inkscape "links" to another SVG document) - for fancy graphics `:)`; however:

    - I know graphviz can somehow use SVG, but I don't know if it just "includes" it as an image, or can you target individual child objects in the SVG? How is node size change hangled (if imported SVG to is just "stretched" in response to node size changing to accomodate label text, then it is useless to me)? ... Couldn't really find any good examples for graphviz with SVG, either
    - It should be somehow possible to define the behavior of the objects contained in the SVG, what to do when the SVG document, here a node (or part of), inevitably changes size to accommodate whatever text the node is supposed to show - e.g. objects that would act like anchors would have the relative (0.0-1.0) position (of their centers) within the document kept fixed, and would not change size in either dimension... Maybe that could be specified via svg attributes, or maybe CSS calc could be used?
- It should be possible to start a connection from an anchor *inside* the port object, in addition to the Graphviz supported [portPos | Graphviz](https://graphviz.org/docs/attr-types/portPos/) ("n", "ne", "e", "se", "s", "sw", "w", "nw", "c", "_")

  - One could define invisible objects inside the Port class at some margin from the edges to act as anchors, and name them "in", "ine", "ie" etc.
- It should be possible to "reduce" the diagram code to something more easily readable, when it comes to actual node and edge instantiation

  - It should be possible to use default settings for some/all properties of a node in a class definition, so these don't have to be repeated (In graphviz, I think that is achieved by `node[...settings...]` before defining any group of nodes with those settings, but I'd really like a "class" based setting instead)
  - A class definition should allow for specifying defaults
  - In case of svg:

    - It should be possible to target child SVG nodes by id or name from the diagram code easily, e.g. `MyNode1:id_PortObj1:id_center` and get/set attributes like .text
- It should be possible to specify the type (like curved, polyline ...) of an *individual* edge (graphviz calls this `splines = spline;`, and AFAIK it can only be set per-document, and in single pass graphviz dot cannot control individual line types; I've read that it can do so in multiple passes, but I've never found a working example of this)

That being said, here is a pseudocode (dot and JSON -like) that I came up with for my Inkscape edited diagram, that illustrates what I imagine would satisfy the above "requirements":

```
splines = spline; // edge type is "spline" for this diagram

nodeclass myNode_btm_conn3 { // node with 3 connectors on bottom
  source: "myNode_btm_conn3.svg",
  port(conn1): "docroot:id_conn1_mysvgobj", // declare port named conn1, defined as a pointer to the SVG group object in the source SVG file, containing the graphics for this port
  port(conn2): "docroot:id_conn2_mysvgobj",
  port(conn3): "docroot:id_conn3_mysvgobj",
  default_anchor(conn1): "docroot:id_conn1_mysvgobj:id_is_mysvgobj", // default anchor is the center of the "inner south" child object of the parent Port class object
  default_anchor(conn2): "docroot:id_conn2_mysvgobj:id_is_mysvgobj",
  default_anchor(conn3): "docroot:id_conn3_mysvgobj:id_is_mysvgobj",
  source: "myNode_btm_conn3.svg",
  prop(title): "docroot:id_title_txt", // declare property, and link it to the right text SVG child object
  prop(prop1): "docroot:id_conn1_mysvgobj:id_prop_1_txt", // declare property, and link it to the right text SVG child object
  prop(prop2): "docroot:id_conn1_mysvgobj:id_prop_2_txt",
  prop(prop3): "docroot:id_conn1_mysvgobj:id_prop_3_txt",
  default_prop_value(prop1): "yes",
  default_prop_value(prop2): "some",
  default_prop_value(prop3): "thing",
};

nodeclass myNode_rsd_conn3 myNode_btm_conn3 { // node with 3 connectors on Right SiDe - inherits defaults from myNode_btm_conn3, except:
  source: "myNode_rsd_conn3.svg", // assume it contains objects with the same SVG
  default_anchor(conn1): "docroot:id_conn1_mysvgobj:id_s_mysvgobj", // since this is SVG, we have to reference a specific object, representing the "south" placed at the border of the node
  default_anchor(conn2): "docroot:id_conn2_mysvgobj:id_s_mysvgobj",
  default_anchor(conn3): "docroot:id_conn1_mysvgobj:id_s_mysvgobj",
};

nodeclass myNode_top_conn6 myNode_btm_conn3 { // node with 6 connectors on top - inherits defaults from myNode_btm_conn3, and adds:
  source: "myNode_top_conn6.svg",
  port(conn4): "docroot:id_conn4_mysvgobj",
  port(conn5): "docroot:id_conn5_mysvgobj",
  port(conn6): "docroot:id_conn6_mysvgobj",
  default_anchor(conn4): "docroot:id_conn4_mysvgobj:id_is_mysvgobj",
  default_anchor(conn5): "docroot:id_conn4_mysvgobj:id_is_mysvgobj",
  default_anchor(conn6): "docroot:id_conn6_mysvgobj:id_is_mysvgobj",
};


// (now comes the instantiation part of the code, which
//  is somewhat more easily readable,  since a lot of the 
//  boilerplate is now tucked away in class defaults))

// instantiate nodes of class (node name is the argument), with settings:

myNode_btm_conn3 node( myNodeA ) {
  title: "Title A";
  // prop_1: "yes", // already set in defaults, no need;
};

myNode_btm_conn3 node( myNodeC ) {
  title: "Title C";
  // note: Inskcape does not seem to recognize "visibility:hidden", and instead uses "display:none" to hide objects in SVG:
  css("docroot:conn1_mysvgobj:prop_1_container"): "display:none;"
};

myNode_rsd_conn3 node( myNodeB ) {
  title: "Title B";
}

myNode_top_conn6 node( myNodeD ) {
  title: "Title D";
};

// edge connections:

edge [dir=both,arrowtail=dot]; // settings for all edges

// these three edges will be linear:
myNodeA:conn1 -> myNodeB:conn1:n [splines = linear];
myNodeA:conn2 -> myNodeB:conn2:n [splines = linear];
myNodeA:conn3 -> myNodeB:conn3:n [splines = linear];

myNodeB:conn1 -> myNodeD:conn4:n;
myNodeB:conn2 -> myNodeD:conn5:n;
myNodeB:conn3 -> myNodeD:conn6:e;

myNodeC:conn1 -> myNodeD:conn1:n;
myNodeC:conn2 -> myNodeD:conn2:n;
myNodeC:conn3 -> myNodeD:conn3:n;
```

So - to what extent can what I want be achieved in graphviz; and are there any alternatives to graphviz where something like this can be achieved?

Comment: [cytoscape-sbgn-stylesheet demo](https://pathwaycommons.github.io/cytoscape-sbgn-stylesheet/) looks like it will do, see [demo.json](https://github.com/PathwayCommons/cytoscape-sbgn-stylesheet/blob/master/demo.json): "... `"class": "simple chemical",`"

Comment: Also, [List of graph visualization libraries | by Elise Devaux | Medium](https://elise-deux.medium.com/the-list-of-graph-visualization-libraries-7a7b89aab6a6) and [Kroki!](https://kroki.io/#try)

Comment: Graphviz can probably produce an image similar/identical to your "edited" image.  Your requirements list is outside the scope of stackoverflow.